# vaadin4spring security sample with touchkit UI

Tags: java, spring, security, maven, gwt

I am coming from this question ([vaadin4spring security sample: failed to load widgetset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578080/vaadin4spring-security-sample-failed-to-load-widgetset)) but would like to go a step further now: I am trying to combine vaadin-touchkit with vaadin4spring-security in order to make a nice mobile UI with login-secured areas/pages. I am expecting that e.g. the login form will not look that nice without adjustments but atm my problem is actually to get the touchkit working at all.

What I have done so far:

- I have added `spring-vaadin-touchkit` in the pom (as well as `vaadin-touchkit-agpl` and `javax.servlet-api` since I haven’t been able to use `SpringAwareTouchKitServlet` otherwise [hierarchy of type classname is inconsistent]).
- I have added `<inherits name="com.vaadin.addon.touchkit.gwt.TouchKitWidgetSet" />` to the widgetset file.
- I have edited LoginUI by replacing `@Theme(“security”)` by `@Theme(“touchkit”)` and adding some basic fields via TabBarView (just to see if it is working).
- I have tried to force widget compilation by `mvn vaadin:compile -Dgwt.compiler.force=true` (BUILD SUCCESS)
- I have edited the `ServletInitializer` class so that it extends `SpringAwareTouchkitServlet` now (configure method of the sample application is basically deleted and therefor the class is empty).

When starting the application, it seems to be working properly. However, when opening the URL on a smartphone the UI looks very small (properly designed but really small like a conventional website that is loaded on a mobile device).

When additionally replacing `@VaadinUI` by `@TouchKitUI`, the loaded page remains empty/white.

Is this issue easily solvable? Or is it in general not that easy to combine the sample-security project with a touchkit UI?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

More details:

- When the loaded page remains blank, Firebug is showing a 404 error. So I would assume, the "forward" path (login) is for some reason not linked to the UI and view (even though I have added the path to the TouchKitUI annotation by `@TouchKitUI(path = "/login")`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding the following annotation to the ApplicationInitializer class solved the problem for me:

```
@EnableTouchKitServlet
```